# Sort an array of char in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, sorting

I have been struggling to write a simple code to sort an array of char in C and been failing miserably. This is what I have so far:

```
int main()
{
  char line[128];
  char word[128];
  int i=0;
  int j;
  int length;

  while(fgets(line,sizeof line,stdin) != NULL)
  {
    length=0;
    i=0;

    while (line[i]!='\0')
      i++;

    length=i;

    line[i-1]=line[i];

    for (i=0;i<=length;i++)
      word[i]=line[i];

    for (i=length-1; i>=0; i--)
    {
      for (j=0;j<i;j++)
      {
        if (line[j] > line[i])
        {
          char temp;
          temp=line[j];
          line[j]=line[i];
          line[i]=temp;
        }
      }
    }

    printf("%s %s\n",line,word);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Original file:

```
overflow
array
test
string
stack
```

Output file:

```
 overflow
 array
 test
 string
 stack
```

This is giving me rather unexpected results. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Can you define "unexpected results"? It works perfectly for me.

Comment: @casablanca: If it works for me, then the problem is somewhere else in my code. Let me look into it

Comment: Maybe your `length` is set incorrectly?

Comment: This is a follow-up/duplicate of [
C program to sort characters in a string
](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3929547/c-program-to-sort-characters-in-a-string).  As I said there, the sort is inefficient but correct.  The output there also shows it working (though there are other errors).

Comment: @Matthew: it was kinda working then. While trying to fix it, it seems I broke it further

Comment: If you print the results with `printf("%s")` make sure you avoid `'\0'`.

Comment: made some edits to add more code and show whats going wrong with my results

Comment: Are you not allowed to use strcpy() and strlen()?

Comment: What's this line supposed to do: `line[i-1]=line[i];` ?

Comment: @JoshD: I think it removes the newline retrieved by `fgets`.

Comment: @Jonathan: I am allowed to use them. I'm just not sure how to

Comment: @Josh: I might be horribly wrong with this one, but here's what I'm trying to achieve with that. Fgets reads in a newline char too, which I do not want, so I copy the null character at line[i] to line[i-1]

Comment: @xbonex it's correct, but don't forget to decrement the length after you do it!

Comment: ASCII NUL '\0' is smaller than all the other characters.  Don't sort it to the front of your string.

Comment: You could use `strlen()` to determine the length of the line input.  You could use `strcpy()` to copy the input `line` to `word`.  Don't forget that `fgets()` includes the newline; you don't want your string to do so, I think.  Don't forget to decrement length once you've nixed the newline.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change:

```
length = i;
```

to:

```
length = i - 1;
```

and it works.

When you do `line[i-1] = line[i];` you are removing the `\n` (which is placed there by `fgets`) from the line and effectively reducing the string length by 1. You should take that into account.

With your current code, the length includes the null terminator, which gets sorted to the beginning of the string, hence your result is an empty string.

Answer (score 2):

Just as I suspected, by avoiding the CR/LF:

```
length=i;
line[i-1]=line[i];
```

you included the `'\0'` characted in the string to be sorted. It will get in the first place, so you'll have an empty string to print.

Answer (score 1):

You are removing the `\n` from the line by overwriting it with `\0` but your `length` calculation is done *before* this change.

To fix this, do

```
line[i-1]=line[i];
```

before you calculate the length.

Since your `length` is one more than the actual length, `\0` is also taking part as a char to be sorted and since its the smallest of all char, it gets placed at the beginning of the string, effectively making your string empty.